# Rails 4, SQ Lite 3: Access model through model without an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got two tables:
*item*
*recipe*

In this example I've got an item object `item` with the id `1`.
The `item` table has one column named `recipe_id`. For this object it has the value `2`.
`recipe` has a column named `title`.
How can I get for example the `title` from the `recipe` of which the `id` is linked in `item`, if I have the item?
Something like...?

```
= item.recipe_id.title
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do the model have any association ?

Comment: that's not the case. my question is, if it is possible to accomplish without an association

Comment: Then maybe not directly in view, but you can always fetch the receipe in controller or do JOIN with `recipe` based on `recipe.id == item.recipe_id`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you couldn't use an association?

Answer (score 0):

you'd use your own SQL to find records in a tableusing find_by_sql. The find_by_sql method will return an array of objects even if the underlying query returns just a single record. For example you could run this query:

for example

```
  Recipe.joins("INNER JOIN item ON <your_conditions_to_get_recipe_related_to_item>")
```

or

```
  Recipe.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM recipe
       INNER JOIN item ON <your_conditions_to_get_recipe_related_to_item>")
```

acording to your case

for example

```
  Recipe.joins("INNER JOIN item ON item.recipe_id = recipe.id and item.id = 1 and recipe.id = 2")
```

with params

```
  Recipe.joins("INNER JOIN item ON item.recipe_id = recipe.id").where("item.id = ? and recipe.id = ?", item_id, recipe_id)
```

these are some ways to access to the database and retrieve a model or models instances without associations ways.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a possible condition? I'm just so bad in SQ Lite :-)

Comment: item.recipe_id = recipe.id and item.id = 1 and recipe.id = 2. That retrieves recipes that exists in item table  for the item 1 and recipe 2